# What is the grammar of the quote: "There isn't a Parallel of Latitude but thinks it would have been the Equator if it had had its rights."?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Though I understand more or less the meaning of this quote, I cannot see
that it is really a grammatical English sentence. It can be found in he
Chapter LXIX of Mark Twain's novel "Following the Equator". Unfortunately, there is no context, since it is only a motto.

Comment: I imagine what's throwing you is the *but*, here. I am not equipped to explain it to you in grammatical terms (I am a native speaker, but no linguist), but I can tell you it means *all parallels of latitude believe they should be the equator* (which is the biggest, most important, most famous parallel of latitude, and the standard by which all latitude is judged), and thus, metaphorically, *everyone thinks he himself is the most important person in the world*. In short "there is no ... but ..." is a fairly uncommon way to say "**without exception**".

Comment: @ Dan Bron Yes, I see. The "but" works as a negation. That is what I could not recognize. So if I understand the matter, the sentence could be rewritten as follows: "There isn't a Parallel of Latitude THAT DOES NOT think it would have been the Equator if it had had its rights."

Comment: "but" = "wh-word not"; here, "but thinks" = "which does not think".

Comment: @GyorgySereny  That is correct. I am hoping one our resident experts will stop by and explain it to you (and me!) in technical grammatical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an archaic use of "but", which would now be expressed as "that doesn't".

It survives in a similar sense as a preposition, meaning "except", ("There isn't anybody but him  that thinks so"), but this use as a conjunction is no longer current.

The OED lists it as meaning 12 b of "but (prep,conj etc)": " b. With omission of the pronominal subject or object of the subord. clause, so that but acts as a negative relative: That..not, who..not. (Latin quin.)" One of the examples (from Keats) is "Not a man but felt the terror in his hair."
(The OED doesn't list this as an archaic meaning, but the entry hasn't been updated since 1888).

Answer (score 0):

Insert "the one which" between "but" and "thinks", and read "but" as "except." He must be intentionally using a colloquial style, where the relativizer is dropped. (e.g., *Here's a man [who] thinks he can win the prize.*) You normally hear this in spoken English, but not written.